# How to read file in C programming using codeanywhere?

Tags: c

[image]
 here is the code given to me and a have also a text file where i need to get the Text from and compile the program.

Comment: Please don't post (unreadable) pictures of code. Post the code directly in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. You really need to show your code from an honest attempt to write the program.  Simply showing a tutor-provided skeleton doesn't meet the 'honest attempt' criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use open a file with `fopen()` first. But the current user needs to have perms to read/write the file.

We will use `r` to only read from a file. If the file is not read it will return `NULL`. You can `fscanf()` function to get the value of a file. The second parameter represents the type of the variable as in this case it's a string(char), third param is the mem address of the variable itself. Kind of like file version of `scanf()`.

```
int main()
{
   char a[1000];
   FILE *myFile;

   if ((myFile = fopen("C:\\myUSER\\newprogram.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(myFile ,"%s", &a);

   printf("Value of a=%s", a);
   fclose(myFile); 

   return 0;
}
```